# Transliteration protocol

Tags: discussion, arabic, transliteration

I think it would be a good idea to have a standard transliteration protocol for writing Arabic terms in English. In one of the answers below, someone can add a table or list of transliteration symbols with corresponding Arabic letters. For example, I prefer saying *arkān* over *arkaan*.

Comment: Difficulty typing vs. difficulty understanding are going to be the two trade-offs in whatever solution rules.

Comment: I think that "arkān" is not easy to type, and not understandable for most of the people.

Answer (score 14):

I would propose basing our system on the one that's been developed for Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Arabic).

The **Basic Transcription** rules (e.g., *arkan* instead of either *arkān* or *arkaan*) should be sufficient for most purposes. If an exact reading is required for something it would probably be better to just quote the Arabic text itself.

Comment: +1 Wikipedia is easily referenced, and provided a good standard.

Answer (score 1):

Having to learn a standard transliteration scheme would be a major barrier to anybody trying to answer questions here. This is something that [I had to come around to myself](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2254/consistency-in-tag-transliteration#comment8587_2254); however, I have been convinced that consistency in transliteration isn't really worth that much. It does make searching the site somewhat easier, but since I don't think it's reasonable to expect that every single post will follow the convention, it's not like it really completely solves that problem anyway. Google is probably a better way of searching the site in any case.

Comment: I agree you somewhat; it could be considered as relatively an appropriate reply. Particularly your initial sentence which said "Having to learn a standard transliteration scheme would be a major barrier to anybody trying to answer questions here."