# Can we synonymize the "makruh" and "makrooh" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I just discovered there are two tags [makruh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makruh) and [makrooh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makrooh).  Neither are listed as having a tag synonym ([makruh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/makruh/synonyms); [makrooh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tags/makrooh/synonyms)).  As far as I'm aware, these are just two transliterations of the same Arabic word.

**Question**: Can we synonymize the "makruh" and "makrooh" tags?

I'd suggest one myself, only I don't know which one is the best transliteration to choose.  I'd guess the best is "makruh" because the of the Wikipedia page [Makruh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makruh).

Comment: I have now created the [tag:makrooh]->[tag:makruh] synonym, and merged the two tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I would recommend *makrooh* because in the same wikipedia it says
**makrooh** or **makrūh**. It is not **u** but **ū**. So we rather
go with the more accurate and easier to use one.
Plus the transliteration of Al-Isra (17) verse [38](https://quran.com/17/38) which has
this word uses **oo** not **ū**.</s>

Based on the concensus [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9/3487), lets go for *makruh*

Comment: Basic Transcription rules (as suggested here http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/9/22) would use "makruh"

Comment: Agreed and edited.