# Can we make "shahadah" a synoynm of "shahada"?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag

Can we make [shahadah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shahadah) (16) a synonym of [shahada](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shahada) (3)?

As per the [transliteration protocol](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/17163): the Wikipedia page is [shahada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahada).

---

We might as well think about a suitable tag wiki excerpt at the same time.  The current one is:

> ash-Shahadah الشهادة is an Islamic creed declaring belief in oneness of God and the acceptance of Muhammad as God's prophet

but this does not meet the guideline "Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is highly specialized." on [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) and [What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts).

Comment: Done and done. Since there were no new suggestions for tag wiki content, I just copied over the [tag:shahadah] tag wiki information to [tag:shahada] rather than leave it blank (mostly verbatim except for some spelling tweaks and copying the warning not to confuse it with ash-Shahadat (martyrdom) from the wiki to the exerpt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should indeed be synonyms as shahada is a shortened form of shahadah which doesn't reflect the pronunciation of the letter taa' تاء at the end of a feminine noun (ending with ة) which sounds like an "h" as is the case for shahadah.

So yes I agree with them being made synonyms!