# Can we re-name the tag for zakat al-fitr?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-mistakes, retagging

We have a tag called [sadqa-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sadqa-fitr), which is wrong from two points of view: the correct Arabic term for a free or optional donation is sadaqa or sadaqah صدقة not sadqa.

The correct term however is zakat al-fitr زكاة الفطر which is a zakat, a prescribed donation.

Therefore I'd like to suggest that we get rid of this wrong term and replace it by a tag "[zakat-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat-fitr)"or "[zakat-al-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat-al-fitr)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia calls it [Zakat al-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakat_al-Fitr) and redirects [Sadaqah al-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadaqah_al-Fitr) to Zakat al-Fitr.  The [transliteration protocol](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/transliteration-protocol) is basically "do what Wikipedia does" (presumably, the authors at Wikipedia have thought about these things carefully), so it makes sense to use the tag [zakat-al-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zakat-al-fitr).

We can use synonymizing and edit the tag wiki excerpt to clarify.

([MuslimAid.org.au](https://www.muslimaid.org.au/donation-types/fitrah-zakat-al-fitr) calls it both of these things along with "Fitrah" and "Fitrana".)

Answer (score 3):

I've seen it used in some books of fiqh, for example see  باب صدقة الفطر in  [Radd al Muhtar](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1538&idto=1557&bk_no=27&ID=93), [Mughni](https://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=1577&idto=1619&bk_no=15&ID=1526) and [Hidayah](https://library.islamweb.net/NewLibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=797&idto=812&bk_no=9&ID=67).

Also the below hadith:

> قال فرض رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم **صدقة الفطر**
>
> <sub>[Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/24/113)</sub>
>
> ‏ ليس في العبد صدقة الا **صدقة الفطر**
>
> <sub>[Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/12/14)</sub>

Maybe زكاة الفطر  can be made a new tag and the present one made a synonym to it?

Comment: I see also the qur'an uses sadaqa instead of zakat, but i'd like to get rid of sadqa as it is simply a wrong transliteration.