# Should we retag questions tagged "eid" with the tags "eid-ul-adha" and/or "eid-ul-fitr"?

Tags: discussion, tag

We currently have two tags:

- [eid](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid) (32 Q's) which is mostly [Eid ul-Fitr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eid_al-Fitr) questions, but we don't have an [eid-ul-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-ul-fitr) tag.
- [eid-ul-adha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-ul-adha) (14 Q's) of which the questions all seem correctly tagged.  And it seems the tag is [appropriately named](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3067/17163).

As I understand, "eid" means "celebration", which clashes with the [celebration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celebration) tag.  It also seems that what "eid" means varies with the time of year (*What are you doing for Eid?*).

My impression is that we should get rid of the tag [eid](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid), and instead use [eid-ul-fitr](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-ul-fitr) and/or [eid-ul-adha](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eid-ul-adha) (and [celebration](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celebration) for other celebrations) where appropriate.

**Question**: Should we retag questions tagged "eid" with the tags "eid-ul-adha" and/or "eid-ul-fitr"?

Comment: What if somebody asks a question on the prayer of eid, or allowed activities on eid, without specification -as it is not needed-? Of course one could then use both tags, but sooner or later a new "eid" tag would appear!